# How to automate the creation of a list based on an integer input in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

This is undoubtedly a very simple problem, but I don't have much experience with coding in Excel.

In this example, I would like the user to input the # of students into cell `B3`.

After inputting the # into the cell (for example, if the person input `5`), I would like to create that number of rows from `A4-A9` based on the notation `Student_#` (Student_1, Student_2, Student_3, Student_4, Student_5).

If the person put in `10`, I would like there to be 10 rows of Student_1 through Student_10 (updated automatically).

The "Student_" will be static as this is an unidentified list, I'd just like to create the number of rows based on this initial input value.

Thanks in advance for any help.

[image: Example Image]

Comment: So you just want to create that many rowsm or you want to populate them with Student_# as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In A5 put:

```
=IF(ROW(A1)<=$B$3,"Student_" & ROW(A1),"")
```

And copy down enough to cover the largest number allowed in `B3`

If one has the Dynamic Array formula simply put:

```
="Student_"&SEQUENCE(B3)
```

In A5 and Excel will spill the results down.